# Exclude curly braces between and get the string - regex

Tags: javascript, regex

To be honest i am not very good at regex . But basically what i need to do is to extract / render the string between the curly braces .

What i have tried until now is :

```
var regexp = /\{\{(.*?)\}\}/
var fruit = '{{Banana}}'
console.log(fruit.replace(regexp , ''));

//Output : ""
```

The idea is to have only the string `Banana` displayed without the curly braces.
I will be glad if someone can land me a hand . Thanks upfront

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `/[{}]/g` to get only the `Banana`

[image]

```js
var regexp = /[{}]/g;
var fruit = "{{Banana}}";
console.log(fruit.replace(regexp, ""));
```

or `/{{(.*?)}}/` with `match`

[image]

```js
var regexp = /{{(.*?)}}/;
var fruit = "{{Banana}}";
const result = fruit.match(regexp)[1];

console.log(result);
```

or if it supports positive look ahead and positive lookbehind

```js
var regexp = /(?<={{).*(?=}})/;
var fruit = "{{Banana}}";
const result = fruit.match(regexp)[0];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the description mate . Now it makes sense . Really thank you for the effort !

Comment: Not a problem. Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

Using `regex` and `string.match()`

```js
const regex = /{+(.*?)}+/i;
const fruit = "{{Banana}}";
console.log(fruit.match(regex)[1]);
```